# Is there any minimum key length is required for JWT_PUBLIC_KEY ? getting error Could not deserialize key data

Tags: python-3.x, django, rsa, django-rest-framework-jwt

i have used restframework_jwt with RS256 algorithm, and successfully created access token. But i am getting a error "Could not deserialize key data." when try to use this token as Authorization in header. i have tried changing the JWT_PUBLIC_KEY.

Right now my setting is like this,

settings.py

```
JWT_AUTH = {
  'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n'+str(SECRET_KEY)+'\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----',
  'JWT_PRIVATE_KEY': '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n'+str(PRIVATE_KEY)+'\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
  'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
  'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
  'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

  'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
  'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

  'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
  'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

  'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
  'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

  'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
  'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',
```

}

views.py

```
class GetUserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = CustomUsers.objects.all()
```

these are version i am using,

```
{
   "cryptography": {
   "version": "2.2"
},
"implementation": {
"name": "CPython",
"version": "3.8.10"
},
 "platform": {
 "release": "5.8.0-63-generic",
 "system": "Linux"
},
"pyjwt": {
 "version": "1.7.1"
}
```

}

please help me to figure out the issue.

Comment: Please share the whole traceback

Comment: When I see this `'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n'+str(SECRET_KEY)+'\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'` , esp. the middle part `str(SECRET_KEY)`, I wonder if you're using proper RSA keys at all

Comment: what i have used is django secret key, which is g1@v8g$+fq_m6p&s&qw=*t#cchftavgk^$ogr*8y+@#&xk2x0. Is there any site where we can generate public key ?

Comment: you can't just take any string, put it between BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY and hope the RSA algortihm takes it. You need a real RSA keypair (private/public key) , eg.  from https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/ Or generate it with openssl.

Comment: suppose i have a private key, i can create the corresponding public key, from this site right ?? https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/

Comment: I think the website only generates new key pairs. To get the public key from your private key see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=generate+public+key+from+private+key

Comment: i have go through the links,i have a doubt.. openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024, this will generate key in mykey.pem right..but i have file.. .json file which contains private key. how can get that key and create public key for that private key. is that possible with openssl ??